# Is there any reason to retain a scheduled NSTimer if you don't need to invalidate it?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstimer

I'm going back over some crufty code to tidy it up and I see I've been retaining NSTimers returned from `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` and storing them in a field - then releasing and nulling the field when it fires. In some cases I use the timer to send an invalidate message to it later - but in many cases not.

In more recent code I usually just schedule the timer and forget about it. I understand that the constructor method is autoreleasing and the timer is retained by the run loop while it is active - so I don't see any issue with this.

So, just to round out my understanding - is there any other reason I should be holding on to my timers, or is what I am doing now the accepted idiom?

This is all in the context of iPhone code, but I don't believe this is iPhone specific.

Answer (score 3):

I just let the run loop handle the retention, myself - it's the run loop that owns the timer and not me. If you see what I mean.

Comment: Yes, this isn't really a memory management question - although I included that in my wording in case there was something I'd misunderstood there. That said, if I was keeping a reference to it I'd retain it anyway - the runloop should release it when it fires.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question.

I was mostly asking the question because I'd been browsing through the class reference docs and this issue was not really made clear. I've since read the Timer Programming Topics: Using Timers article in the ADC and it covers it pretty well - especially the section on memory management at the end.

According to that what I am doing now (just scheduling, unless I need to be able to call invalidate, or isValid etc) is the right way.

Comment: I have been banging my head trying to figure out why my call to invalidate was crashing! I was NOT retaining the timer. Strange behavior though, is that if you use if(myTimer){[myTimer invalidate];} will crash without timer being retained, so don't understand why it was getting by the IF statement, but this seems to have solved it!

Comment: Here is related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399669/iphone-crash-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance

Comment: @jsherk - if your unretained timer is released before your if then your own copy of the pointer will still have a value - it will just no longer point to an allocated object (or at least not the one you thought it was) - so a crash is exactly what you'd except (although, worse still, it may not crash!)

Comment: @jsherk: Expanding on what philsquared said, that crashed because you didn't set `myTimer` to `nil` after invalidating it, so you were trying to invalidate the same timer multiple times. The first time killed it off, and your subsequent attempts were attempts to talk to a dead object.